# Create toggle functionality for keyboard in LUA script (logitech G hub)

Tags: lua, macros, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

this will be my first post here.
I am trying to create a script that works as a toggle using LUA
the functionality I want is a single key "G1" which initiates a loop when pressed and breaks the loop when pressed again.

my code:

```lua
local msMakro = false
local safety = 0
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    
    --MS MAKRO--
    if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then
        OutputLogMessage("\nG1 Pressed \n")

        msMakro = not msMakro
        OutputLogMessage("msMakro = ")
        OutputLogMessage(tostring(msMakro))
        OutputLogMessage("\n")
    end
      
    while (msMakro and safety < 5) do
        PressAndReleaseKey("a")
        Sleep(math.random(1000, 1500))
        safety = safety +1
        OutputLogMessage("safety = ")
        OutputLogMessage(safety)
        OutputLogMessage("\n")        
    end
end
```

the following code does not allow to break the loop pressing the button again it will just queue the call and display it in the terminal once the while is exited on the safety condition

I've looked for similar problems but did not seem to find a solution that worked for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign "Back" action to the <kbd>G1</kbd> key.
"Back" action is the standard assignment for Mouse Button 4.
So, now your <kbd>G1</kbd> key acts as "Backward" mouse button, and you can monitor its state with `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)`.

```
local msMakro = false
local safety = 0

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    --MS MAKRO--
    if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
        OutputLogMessage("\nG1 Pressed \n")
        msMakro = not msMakro
        OutputLogMessage("msMakro = ")
        OutputLogMessage(tostring(msMakro))
        OutputLogMessage("\n")
        while msMakro and safety < 5 do
            PressAndReleaseKey("a")
            local tm = GetRunningTime() + math.random(1000, 1500)
            local prev_mb4 = true
            repeat
                Sleep(10)
                local mb4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
                if mb4 and not prev_mb4 then return end
                prev_mb4 = mb4
            until GetRunningTime() > tm
            safety = safety +1
            OutputLogMessage("safety = ")
            OutputLogMessage(safety)
            OutputLogMessage("\n")
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
I copied your code but it still didn't allow me to break the loop
I bound the G1 key to middle mouse which enables me to scroll using he G1 key
and then I tried the exact same as you have shown above just with middle mouse (mb3)


did you try it out yourself?

Comment: For MMB use `IsMouseButtonPressed(2)`

Comment: are you sure? when I press middle mouse button it shows arg: 3 in the console so i assumed 3 would be middle mouse
and when i press right mouse button (secondary) it says arg: 2 so i assume 2 is right mouse click
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wow that is so miss guiding in fact middle mouse is 2 yet the console says it is arg 3.
thank you! it works as intended with your code.
i guess i will have to refer to this table to get the right mapping:
https://i.imgur.com/fvgI8ZD.png

Comment: now that is see it works, im trying to understand why. is it necessary to have both repeat and while? from my understanding while and repeat are the same.
i do however pick up that you declared the random time variable to later use it in the repeat loop. is that because the inner loop is used to check if we pressed the g1 key and if so we break the whole process. would that mean if we trigger the function and at some point when we want to break the loop and at that time we didn't get inside the repeat loop, then nothing will happen?

Comment: The outer loop (while) is needed for your logic with `safety` variable.  You may remove it if you don't need this `safety`.

Comment: `when we want to break the loop and at that time we didn't get inside the repeat loop, then nothing will happen?` - All `Sleep()` is inside the repeat loop, so the script will always detect G1 key press which I believe is always longer than 10 ms.

Comment: oooh, makes sense Thanks! now that I have moved on with my script I have a question that maybe you may know the answer to. - Is it possible to store functioncalls in an array?
such as: https://i.imgur.com/fcUUeTL.png

Comment: You can create array of functions: `{function() hit() end, function() PressWithDelay(....) end}`